# Does Node.js prioritize I/O event over setTimeout()?

Tags: node.js

The documentation is not terribly clear on how Node.js treats calls scheduled by setTimeout:

> Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when the
>   callback will fire, nor of the ordering things will fire in. The
>   callback will be called as close as possible to the time specified.

Say there's an expired timer. There're also some I/O events waiting to be handled. Will Node.js elect to process all the I/O events first before firing the timer? This is how WM_TIMER works in Windows. I'm guessing Node.js might behave in the same way. Otherwise, why would there be setImmediate()? People could just use setTimeout() with a 0 delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers currently are processed before I/O handlers. Also if you do `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, node schedules the function for the next tick.

Here's an older diagram that shows roughly what happens in one loop of the event loop:

[image: node.js event loop diagram]

Although some things such as the note about `process.maxDepth` are no longer the case in node v0.11+/iojs.

Answer (score 0):

Event loop in node.js (libuv actually) has several phases. In each phase events of some specific types are processed. When all callbacks are called the loop goes one with the next phase: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c#L314.

This means that events of one type can't preempt events of another. Basically there is no single queue, rather per-phase queues.